# Можно ли сказать "гуманные факторы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "гуманные факторы"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово "**гуманный**" (направленный на благо людей) выражает положительную *субъективную* оценку намерений или содержания чьих-то действий. *Факторы* же (действующие причины) складываются стихийно или объективно, поэтому можно говорить о **гуманитарных** факторах (имеющих влияние на благополучие людей или связанных с поведением больших групп людей) и нельзя о **гуманных**.